# What is order Firebase use to retrieve data from server?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two tables: friend_lists and users[image]

I want to retrieve data from both. After get data from friend_lists table, I use uidfriend to get data from users. I use two method:

```
DataSnapshot ds;
private void getPrivateMessages(){
        ValueEventListener valueEventListenerPrivateMessage = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Log.v("data Private message", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();//it works fine.
                ds= dataSnapShot;


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
            databaseReferenceFriendLists.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(valueEventListenerPrivateMessage);
    }
    private void getFriendInfo(){
        getPrivateMessage();
        ValueEventListener valueEventListenerFriendInfo = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.v("data friend info", dataSnapShot.getValue().toString);
                Log.v("ds Private Message", ds.getValue().toString());//error: null variable
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        databaseReferenceUsers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListenerFriendInfo);
    }
```

But my app crashed and announced null variable to me. And in logcat, it shown "data friend info" first even though i run getPrivateMessage(); first(it must be "data Private message" first then "data friend info").

What 's wrong in my code? I don't know the way firebase runs.

Comment: Firebase events will respond back based on the time taken for the requested query its not guarantee that order is same as the initiated all are threads, it means if **data friend info** has less number of records then **ds Private Message** , **data friend info**  data it will respond first,

Comment: Ok i must use another way to get my data. Thank u very much!